# Desplegar lista de tipo Dynamic en ListView Xamarin Form

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación en la que los datos los estoy obteniendo directo de una Base de Datos, éstos los almaceno dentro de una variable de tipo `dynamic` para posteriormente meterlos en una lista y poderlos mostrar en un `ListView`, pero al momento de ejecutar la aplicación, no me muestra nada en el celular. La razón por la que estoy haciendo uso de una variable de tipo **Dynamic** para almacenar los datos es por que en la aplicación se debe de mostrar en un **ListView** todas las tablas que se encuentran en la Base de Datos, aun si en un futuro se llegaran a insertar nuevas tablas dentro de la Base de Datos. Esa es la razón por la que no puedo dejar modelos ya definidos de las estructuras de las tablas, porque no puedo conocer las estructuras de las tablas que se irán agregando en un futuro a la BD.

Hice un ejemplo de que es lo que estoy intentando hacer con una lista de tipo Dynamic, pero no me muestra los datos en pantalla. Les agradecería mucho si me podrían ayudar a solucionarlo.

```
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
            {
                private ListView lv_inst;
                private StackLayout st_inst, stk1;

                public MainPage()
                {
                    Title = "Lista";
                    CrearGUIAsync();
                }

                public void CrearGUIAsync()
                {
                    lv_inst = new ListView()
                    {
                        HasUnevenRows = true,
                        ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(ResultCell10))
                    };
                    var stk_2 = new StackLayout()
                    {
                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        Children =
                        {
                            lv_inst
                        }
                    };

                    st_inst = new StackLayout()
                    {

                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        Children =
                        {
                            stk_2
                        }
                    };
                    Content = st_inst;
                }
                protected override async void OnAppearing()
                {
                    base.OnAppearing();
                    try
                    {
                        lv_inst.IsVisible = false;
                        List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>();
                        dynamic dObj = new ExpandoObject();
                        dObj.id = "1";
                        dObj.nombre = "Juan";
                        dObj.apellido = "Moreno";
                        dObj.edad = "22";
                        list.Add(dObj);
                        lv_inst.ItemsSource = list;
                        lv_inst.IsVisible = true;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) { await DisplayAlert("", e.StackTrace, ""); }
                }
            }

            class ResultCell10 : ViewCell
            {
                public ResultCell10()
                {
                    int heigh = 35;

                    List<String> propiedad = new List<string>();
                    List<Label> lLabel = new List<Label>();

                    propiedad.Add("id");
                    propiedad.Add("nombre");
                    propiedad.Add("apellido");
                    propiedad.Add("edad");

                    var i = 0;

                    foreach (var cam in propiedad)
                    {
                        lLabel.Add(
                            new Label()
                            {
                                FontSize = 10,
                                HeightRequest = heigh,
                                WidthRequest = 60,
                                TextColor = Color.Black,
                                FontFamily = "Roboto"
                            }
                         );
                        lLabel[i].SetBinding(Label.TextProperty, propiedad[i]);
                        i++;
                    }

                    var stackList = new StackLayout
                    {
                        Padding = new Thickness(10),
                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                        VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                        HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                    };

                    foreach (var l in lLabel)
                    {
                        stackList.Children.Add(l);
                    }
                    View = stackList;
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

se debe crear previamente el StackLayout con el x:Name="stackList" y este mismo hacerlo referencia para añadir dinamicamente los controles  stackList.Children.Add(control)

XAML

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                 x:Class="ButtonDemos.BasicButtonClickPage"
                 Title="Basic Button Click">
        <StackLayout x:Name="stackList">


        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage>
```